# Why do I get a 403 when sending this data to an API via POST?

Tags: php, api, curl, post

We have an API that works with Bearer authentication (https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev/api/cuestionario), which should return the following:

```
{
    "res": "OK",
    "payload": {
        "name": "Hello"
    }
}
```

As you can see here: https://reqbin.com/he9hier5

This is my PHP code:

```
$url = "http://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev/api/cuestionario";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer d8TPqowoqP7CGAzVCy3SJykcZ83fVWl0",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"name": "Hello"}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

But when I execute this file, I get:

```
string(430) "Redirecting you to https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev:443/api/cuestionario"
```

And then, I get a 403 error (forbidden).

What am I doing wrong? I even have tried to copy the code that generates https://reqbin.com/ and nothing, I keep getting a forbidden.

**EDIT: I have just been told by the API programmer, that I will not be able to access the service in any way from the browser, as it does not have CORS enabled. I know what CORS is, but would this prevent me from doing what I am trying to do?**

Comment: Sharing the actual URL and token is something which makes me wonder whether you know anything about APIs at all - we cannot know why you have a 403. You have to talk to the developer of the API and discuss with him how you have to send your requests.

Comment: @maio290 It's a test API, don't worry. Yes, I have talked with him and I'm sending the data correctly. Besides, you can check here that doing the same, I get a response: https://reqbin.com/he9hier5

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't realise that it was a development system. Check out my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Why not use https in the request, as the redirect indicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any trouble testing the request with Insomnia either, therefore the request itself is fine as verified by your own tests.

However, your problem is the actual response from the server - in your case this is:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>Redirecting</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="1; url=https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev:443/api/cuestionario">
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="location.replace('https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev:443/api/cuestionario'+document.location.hash)">
Redirecting you to https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev:443/api/cuestionario</BODY></HTML>
```

and this seems to be enough to redirect with `var_dump` and `echo` - therefore I'd recommend you to use the proper URL (`https`) directly since it's redirected anyway to it:

```
$url = "https://fromero-marca-blanca.deno.dev/api/cuestionario";
```

This resolves your issue.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I don't know how I missed that stupid detail ...

Comment: @Caín Happens: Just a hint for further stuff like that - if the location in your browser changes from a echo on the server, you can always wrap the response in a textarea, this is sometimes better than echoing stuff directly :)

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, try adding the lines that you didn't add.

```
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If you want a permanent solution you should declare in your php.ini file the location of a certificate file. [Read more](https://www.saotn.org/dont-turn-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-fix-php-configuration/)

Comment: Yes, I already tried to add those two lines but the performance is the same, unfortunately

Comment: I downvoted because trusting everyone isn't the purpose of SSL and doesn't seem to have anything in common with OP's problem (a 403 is NOT an SSL error). This just opens a new attack vector (although unlikely) without serving any purpose.